# Extend Volume Group for PE

Tags: linux, ssd, centos

I'm trying to extend a volume group in CentOS and it's being mean.

I've tried for about two hours... no luck.

Anyway, I need to extend VolGroup00 so it's not reporting 0 free PE. There's definitely plenty of PE available...

```
   --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup00
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               238.16 GB
  PE Size               32.00 MB
  Total PE              7621
  Alloc PE / Size       7621 / 238.16 GB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               6ys4Yt-3ZSp-namT-wKs2-dpZj-uBRh-vQ9YOA
```

I have 4 128GB SSDs in a RAID10 config if that matters.

Comment: In my calculations 4x128 GB in RAID10 is 256GB. This is what you got. How you plan to extend it when there are no Free PE available?

Comment: Please provide more details, what partitions do you have, what did you try, e.t.c.